# Organs & Oscillations: An Analysis on the Temperature Dynamics of Solids

Tags: temperature, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, solid-mechanics

Does temperature have an influence on the frequency of an oscillating organ pipe?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, principally because the speed of sound depends on the temperature. An [approximate equation for the speed of sound in dry air](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/Class/sound/u11l2c.cfm) is:

$$ v = 331 + 0.6T $$

The wavelength is fixed by the pipe length so if the speed of sound changes the frequency also changes according to:

$$ f = \frac{v}{\lambda} $$

In principle there will be some thermal expansion of the material making up the organ pipe, but this will be a much smaller effect. Organ pipes are made from a lead alloy, and the [expansion coefficient of lead](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/linear-expansion-coefficients-d_95.html) (I don't have figures for the alloy) is only $2.8 \times 10^{-5}$/K.

Comment: For a sense of scale, if the pipe is tuned to A440 at $22^\circ\mathrm{C}$, then I believe the above formulas, neglecting thermal expansion, say it will play an A♯ at $56^\circ\mathrm{C}$.

Comment: Though if the temperature inside the church is 56°C you probably have more urgent problems than the organ tuning :-)